# Check of microbenchmark results fails with data.table changed by reference

Tags: r, data.table, microbenchmark

There are some answers on SO where timings are compared *without* checking the results. However, I prefer to see whether an expression is correct *and* fast.

The `microbenchmark` package supports this with the `check` parameter. Unfortunately, the check fails on expressions which change a `data.table` *by reference*, i.e., the check does not recognize that results are different.

## Case 1: data.table expressions where check works as expected

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

# minimal data.table 1 col, 3 rows
dt <- data.table(x = c(1, 1, 10))

# define check function as in example section of help(microbenchmark)
my_check <- function(values) {
  all(sapply(values[-1], function(x) identical(values[[1]], x)))
}
```

The benchmark cases are designed to return different results. Thus,

```
microbenchmark(
  f1 = dt[, mean(x)],
  f2 = dt[, median(x)],
  check = my_check
)
```

returns an error message as expected:

> Error: Input expressions are not equivalent.

## Case 2: data.table expressions where check fails

Now, the expressions are modified to change `dt` by reference. Please, note that the same check function is used.

```
microbenchmark(
  f1 = dt[, y := mean(x)],
  f2 = dt[, y := median(x)],
  check = my_check
)
```

returns now

```
 expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
   f1 576.947 625.174 642.9820 640.7110 661.1870 732.391   100  a 
   f2 602.022 658.384 684.7076 678.9975 694.0825 978.600   100   b
```

So, the check on the results has failed here although the two expressions *are* different. (Timings are irrelevant.)

I understand that the check is determined to fail because `dt` is changed by reference. So, when comparing the result of each expression always the same object is referenced in the state of the last change.

## Question

How can I modify the check function and/or the expressions so that the check reliably will detect differing results even in case of a `data.table` being changed by reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `copy()`:

```
microbenchmark(
    f1 = copy(dt)[, y := mean(x)],
    f2 = copy(dt)[, y := median(x)],
    check = my_check, times=1L
)
# Error: Input expressions are not equivalent.
```

Adding `copy(dt)` to the mix would give an idea on the time spent on copying (and if necessary, one could always subtract that from the runtimes for `f1` and `f2`).

```
microbenchmark(
    f1 = copy(dt)[, y := mean(x)],
    f2 = copy(dt)[, y := median(x)],
    f3 = copy(dt),
    times=10L
)
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval cld
#    f1 298.690 306.508 331.6364 315.1400 347.788 414.264    10   b
#    f2 319.075 322.475 373.3873 329.3895 336.268 746.134    10   b
#    f3  19.180  19.750  28.3504  25.1745  26.111  70.016    10   a
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a straightforward solution, concise and easy to implement. +2 for the hint to benchmark `copy()` separately.